# jQuery menu in need of additional functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to create a small and lean as possible menu that hides itself on scroll at certain viewport height, shows itself after You click a button, and I did, but I have 2 problems with it:

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL435Lgk/1/)** for You to follow along.

- When you show the menu by clicking the button it appears, but the only way for it to go away is if You scroll down or up. How can I make it dissapear if I click somewhere out of the #sideBar container e.g. the site.
- When You refresh the page using a soft-refresh (F5) the menu appears because the browser understands that as if the page have been scrolled. Is there a way to bypass this as well?

Here is some code, just because the fiddle requires it:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 400) {
        $('#sideBar').slideUp("fast");
        $('#menuButton').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#sideBar').slideDown("slow");
        $('#menuButton').fadeOut();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menuButton').click(function(){
        $('#sideBar').slideDown();
    })
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey.... Is this what you wanted to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/czqdnnuh/

Comment: @Shivi - your code does nothing and you need to change the fiddle to head instead of onload

Comment: Do not ask more than one unrelated question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the target:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8wLt13kr/)

```
function hideIt() {
        $('#sideBar').slideUp("fast");
        $('#menuButton').fadeIn();

}
function showIt() {
        $('#sideBar').slideDown("slow");
        $('#menuButton').fadeOut();
}

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        hideIt()
    } else {
        showIt();
    }
});

$(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 400) showIt(); // show at start

    $('#menuButton').click(function(){
        $('#sideBar').slideDown();
    });
    $(document).on("click",function(e) {
      var target = $(e.target);
      var show = target.is("#sideBar") || 
                 target.is("#menuButton") || 
                 target.parent().is("#menuButton");
      if (!show) hideIt();
  });    
});
```

Here is a shorter version

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/z4m1hxgf/)

```
function toggleIt(show) {
    if (show) {
        $('#sideBar').slideDown("slow");
        $('#menuButton').fadeOut();
    }    
    else {
        $('#sideBar').slideUp("fast");
        $('#menuButton').fadeIn();
  }
}    

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    toggleIt(y > 400);
});

$(function(){
    toggleIt($(document).scrollTop()<400);

    $('#menuButton').click(function(){
        $('#sideBar').slideDown();
    });
    $(document).on("click",function(e) {
      var target = $(e.target);
      var show = target.is("#sideBar") || 
                 target.is("#menuButton") || 
                 target.parent().is("#menuButton");
      if (!show) toggleIt(false);
    });    
});
```

Comment: This works as well, but when I refresh the browser on my computer, not in the fiddle > the menu appears if I am below the 400px of scroll buffer, and this is logically valid jquery-wise, but is there a way to hide the menu if I refresh the page while being located below those 400px of buffer?

Answer (score 1):

I can help with the first question, you can change your JQuery code below so that when the parent 'content' container is clicked the menu slides up.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#menuButton').click(function(){
        $('#sideBar').slideDown();
      })

      $('#content').click(function(){
        $('#sideBar').slideUp();
      })
   });
```

I'm not sure I follow the second question? Please can you provide more information on what you mean.

Comment: The comments below @Gagan Jaura's response should explain this for you.

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1, Just put the following code in ready function

```
$('#content').click(function(){
    $('#sideBar').slideUp();
});
```

**EDITED**

For Question 2, put following code in ready function

```
$(document).trigger('scroll');
```

In short, your ready function should look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).trigger('scroll'); 

$('#menuButton').click(function(){
    $('#sideBar').slideDown();
})

$('#content').click(function(){
    $('#sideBar').slideUp();
})
```

});

Comment: This works, but the menu needs to be visible until the window is scrolled for 400px further below.

Comment: You can get either this functionality or Question 2 functionality because on F5, page is refreshed and all the variables are reset. It will take the default setting which in your case is to display side bar until user scroll 400px.

Comment: Given this information I assume that what i want to achieve is not possible at this moment.

Comment: I think you can try one more thing, just write below code in ready function and test it. As  I am not able to test on fiddle the functionality of F5 as it reloads the whole page `$(document).trigger('scroll');`

Comment: Basically I want you to check the scrollTop on document ready function. In that way if browser even scroll to your last page, it will check the scrollTop and if it is greater than 400px then it will hide the menu. What say?

Comment: I am not sure I understand You. Can You re-phrase?

Comment: I have edited in my solution, instead of show and hide, just trigger the scroll event on ready function. It will automatically check for scroll position and will slide down or up.

Answer (score 0):

A child, combination of @mplungjan and @Gagan Jaura's responses seems to do the job:

```
function hideIt() {
    $('#sideBar').slideUp("fast");
    $('#menuButton').fadeIn();

}

function showIt() {
    $('#sideBar').slideDown("slow");
    $('#menuButton').fadeOut();
}

$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

if (y > 400) {
        hideIt()
    } else {
        showIt();
    }
});

$(function(){
showIt(); // show at start

$('#menuButton').click(function(){
    $('#sideBar').slideDown();
});
$(document).on("click",function(e) {
      var target = $(e.target);
      var show = target.is("#sideBar") ||
                 target.is("#menuButton") ||
                 target.parent().is("#menuButton");
      if (!show) hideIt();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).trigger('scroll');
    $('#menuButton').click(function(){
    $('#sideBar').slideDown();
})

$('#content').click(function(){
        $('#sideBar').slideUp();
    })
});
```

Comment: If someone can provide an even leaner solution, that would be great. If not, I will give this post a green tick for others to review in the future.

Comment: So you added `$(document).trigger('scroll');` and doubled up on the content click outside the ready? The second part is not a good idea.

Comment: "$(document).trigger('scroll');" alone didn't fix the problem with the refresh. The whole block provided by @Gagan Jaura, combined with Your code seems to do the job. Yes, there is a small visual "glitch" as it scrolls down and up real fast for a fraction of a second, but I think it is okay.

Comment: See my update. I toggle onload if the document.top is > 400

Comment: Your latest code causes some weird behavior hiding the menu exactly on scroll and showing it after 400px and hiding it again.

Comment: and if you switch `toggleIt($(document).scrollTop()<400);` for `$(document).trigger('scroll');`  ?

Comment: This works, but it is the exact opposite of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Then perhaps I need to swap < 400 and > 400

Comment: Yes, excuse my oblivion. This is 99.9% perfect. Thank You very much!